# Convert CString to LPTSTR and LPCTSTR

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, cstring

If CString to LPCTSTR (const), cast it directly. Am I correct?

If CString to LPTSTR, call GetBuffer() and ReleaseBuffer() between the block that use the LPTSTR variable. Am I correct?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/awkwbzyc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can get an unmodifiable view of the underlying character array by casting, which calls CString's conversion operator.

And you can get a writable buffer by calling GetBuffer(), and you should call ReleaseBuffer() when you're done writing it, and want to use the CString again.